# Trigger an alert in GCP Monitoring with more than a certain number of tasks in a Cloud tasks queue and with a retries value > 0

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

Is there a way to create an alert policy in GCP Monitoring that triggers an incident if there are more than 50 tasks in a Cloud Tasks queue with a retries value greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it's not possible to combine each metric to work with each other as you want it. Each condition is separate from each other as metric-based alerting policies are used to track metric data collected by Cloud Monitoring. Cloud Tasks is also currently not a monitored resource for [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#custom-metric-resources).

Cloud Tasks currently have the following [metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudtasks) relevant to your use case:

1. Queue depth
2. Task attempt count

You can set multiple conditions per policy and each condition can relate to a Cloud Tasks metric. What will happen is that an incident will be created if there are more than 50 tasks on a queue, or/and if one of your tasks have a retry higher than 0.

For more information, feel free to check [Introduction to Alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts).